# How do I enable info logging using the Azure Core Logger for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure

### Context

I'm writing an application that uses a library from the [Azure SDK for JS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js), and want to enable logging for the library I am using in my code. It looks like the Azure Libraries use Azure Core Logger ([`@azure/logger`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/logger)).

#### Question

How do I enable logging while running my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the npm page for the @azure/logger package you can find out the answer to this question.

> The @azure/logger package supports the following log levels specified in order of most verbose to least verbose:
>
> - verbose
> - info
> - warning
> - error
>
> When setting a log level, either
> programmatically or via the AZURE_LOG_LEVEL environment variable, any
> logs that are written using a log level equal to or less than the one
> you choose will be emitted.
>
> For example, setting the log level to warning will cause all logs that
> have the log level warning or error to be emitted.

So if you have an application there are two options, either set the environment variable `AZURE_LOG_LEVEL` to either `'info'`, `'verbose'`, `'warning'`, `'error'`.

Alternatively you can programmatically set the log level. Here's the snippet:

```
const { EventHubClient } = require('@azure/event-hubs');

constst logger = require('@azure/logger');
logger.setLogLevel('info');

// operations will now emit info, warning, and error logs
const client = new EventHubClient(/* params */);
client.getPartitionIds()
  .then(ids => { /* do work */ })
  .catch(e => { /* do work */ });
});
```